# Is it possible using function doesn't exists?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, gridfs-stream

When I print

> let app = express()

on console it prints like this.

```
{ [EventEmitter: app]
  _events: { mount: [Function: onmount] },
  _eventsCount: 1,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  setMaxListeners: [Function: setMaxListeners],
  getMaxListeners: [Function: getMaxListeners],
  emit: [Function: emit],
  addListener: [Function: addListener],
  on: [Function: addListener],
  prependListener: [Function: prependListener],
  once: [Function: once], 
  ...
}
```

Inside of code snippet, there is an on: function and etc... so I think this makes me possible to use function on like this app.on(...)

```
const Grid = require('gridfs-stream');

let gfs;
       conn.once('open', () => {
    // Init stream
    gfs = Grid(conn.db, mongoose.mongo);
    gfs.collection('uploads');
    console.log(gfs);
 });
```

But, when I print gfs object on console it prints this.
Here is my example link: https://github.com/qkreltms/mongodb_simple_file_upload_to_db_example/blob/master/app.js

```
Grid {
  db:
   Db {
     _events:
      { reconnect: [Function], close: [Function], timeout: [Function] },
     _eventsCount: 3,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     s:
      { databaseName: 'imgSaveTest',
        dbCache: {},
        children: [],
        topology: [Server],
        options: [Object],
        logger: [Logger],
        bson: BSON {},
        readPreference: [ReadPreference],
        bufferMaxEntries: -1,
        parentDb: null,
        pkFactory: undefined,
        nativeParser: undefined,
        promiseLibrary: [Function: Promise],
        noListener: false,
        readConcern: undefined },
     serverConfig: [Getter],
     bufferMaxEntries: [Getter],
     databaseName: [Getter] },
  mongo:
   { [Function]
     MongoError: [Function: MongoError],
     MongoNetworkError: [Function: MongoNetworkError],
     Admin: [Function: Admin],
     MongoClient:
      { [Function: MongoClient] super_: [Function], connect: [Circular] },
     Db:
      { [Function: Db]
        super_: [Function],
        SYSTEM_NAMESPACE_COLLECTION: 'system.namespaces',
        SYSTEM_INDEX_COLLECTION: 'system.indexes',
        SYSTEM_PROFILE_COLLECTION: 'system.profile',
        SYSTEM_USER_COLLECTION: 'system.users',
        SYSTEM_COMMAND_COLLECTION: '$cmd',
        SYSTEM_JS_COLLECTION: 'system.js' },
     Collection: [Function: Collection],
     Server: [Function: Server],
     ReplSet: [Function: ReplSet],
     Mongos: [Function: Mongos],
     ReadPreference:
      { [Function: ReadPreference]
        PRIMARY: 'primary',
        PRIMARY_PREFERRED: 'primaryPreferred',
        SECONDARY: 'secondary',
        SECONDARY_PREFERRED: 'secondaryPreferred',
        NEAREST: 'nearest',
        isValid: [Function],
        primary: [ReadPreference],
        primaryPreferred: [ReadPreference],
        secondary: [ReadPreference],
        secondaryPreferred: [ReadPreference],
        nearest: [ReadPreference] },
     GridStore:
      { [Function: GridStore]
        DEFAULT_ROOT_COLLECTION: 'fs',
        DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE: 'binary/octet-stream',
        IO_SEEK_SET: 0,
        IO_SEEK_CUR: 1,
        IO_SEEK_END: 2,
        exist: [Function],
        list: [Function],
        read: [Function],
        readlines: [Function],
        unlink: [Function] },
     Chunk: { [Function: Chunk] DEFAULT_CHUNK_SIZE: 261120 },
     Logger:
      { [Function: Logger]
        reset: [Function],
        currentLogger: [Function],
        setCurrentLogger: [Function],
        filter: [Function],
        setLevel: [Function] },
     AggregationCursor:
      { [Function: AggregationCursor] super_: [Function], INIT: 0, OPEN: 1, CLOSED: 2 },
     CommandCursor:
      { [Function: CommandCursor] super_: [Function], INIT: 0, OPEN: 1, CLOSED: 2 },
     Cursor:
      { [Function: Cursor] super_: [Function], INIT: 0, OPEN: 1, CLOSED: 2, GET_MORE: 3 },
     GridFSBucket: { [Function: GridFSBucket] super_: [Function] },
     CoreServer:
      { [Function: Server]
        super_: [Function],
        enableServerAccounting: [Function],
        disableServerAccounting: [Function],
        servers: [Function] },
     CoreConnection:
      { [Function: Connection]
        super_: [Function],
        enableConnectionAccounting: [Function],
        disableConnectionAccounting: [Function],
        connections: [Function] },
     Binary:
      { [Function: Binary]
        BUFFER_SIZE: 256,
        SUBTYPE_DEFAULT: 0,
        SUBTYPE_FUNCTION: 1,
        SUBTYPE_BYTE_ARRAY: 2,
        SUBTYPE_UUID_OLD: 3,
        SUBTYPE_UUID: 4,
        SUBTYPE_MD5: 5,
        SUBTYPE_USER_DEFINED: 128,
        Binary: [Circular] },
     Code: { [Function: Code] Code: [Circular] },
     Map: { [Function: Map] Map: [Circular] },
     DBRef: { [Function: DBRef] DBRef: [Circular] },
     Double: { [Function: Double] Double: [Circular] },
     Int32: { [Function: Int32] Int32: [Circular] },
     Long:
      { [Function: Long]
        fromInt: [Function],
        fromNumber: [Function],
        fromBits: [Function],
        fromString: [Function],
        INT_CACHE_: [Object],
        TWO_PWR_16_DBL_: 65536,
        TWO_PWR_24_DBL_: 16777216,
        TWO_PWR_32_DBL_: 4294967296,
        TWO_PWR_31_DBL_: 2147483648,
        TWO_PWR_48_DBL_: 281474976710656,
        TWO_PWR_64_DBL_: 18446744073709552000,
        TWO_PWR_63_DBL_: 9223372036854776000,
        ZERO: [Long],
        ONE: [Long],
        NEG_ONE: [Long],
        MAX_VALUE: [Long],
        MIN_VALUE: [Long],
        TWO_PWR_24_: [Long],
        Long: [Circular] },
     MinKey: { [Function: MinKey] MinKey: [Circular] },
     MaxKey: { [Function: MaxKey] MaxKey: [Circular] },
     ObjectID:
      { [Function: ObjectID]
        index: 4899462,
        createPk: [Function: createPk],
        createFromTime: [Function: createFromTime],
        createFromHexString: [Function: createFromHexString],
        isValid: [Function: isValid],
        ObjectID: [Circular],
        ObjectId: [Circular] },
     ObjectId:
      { [Function: ObjectID]
        index: 4899462,
        createPk: [Function: createPk],
        createFromTime: [Function: createFromTime],
        createFromHexString: [Function: createFromHexString],
        isValid: [Function: isValid],
        ObjectID: [Circular],
        ObjectId: [Circular] },
     Symbol: { [Function: Symbol] Symbol: [Circular] },
     Timestamp:
      { [Function: Timestamp]
        fromInt: [Function],
        fromNumber: [Function],
        fromBits: [Function],
        fromString: [Function],
        INT_CACHE_: [Object],
        TWO_PWR_16_DBL_: 65536,
        TWO_PWR_24_DBL_: 16777216,
        TWO_PWR_32_DBL_: 4294967296,
        TWO_PWR_31_DBL_: 2147483648,
        TWO_PWR_48_DBL_: 281474976710656,
        TWO_PWR_64_DBL_: 18446744073709552000,
        TWO_PWR_63_DBL_: 9223372036854776000,
        ZERO: [Timestamp],
        ONE: [Timestamp],
        NEG_ONE: [Timestamp],
        MAX_VALUE: [Timestamp],
        MIN_VALUE: [Timestamp],
        TWO_PWR_24_: [Timestamp],
        Timestamp: [Circular] },
     BSONRegExp: { [Function: BSONRegExp] BSONRegExp: [Circular] },
     Decimal128:
      { [Function: Decimal128] fromString: [Function], Decimal128: [Circular] },
     connect: [Circular],
     instrument: [Function] },
  curCol: 'uploads',
  _col:
   Collection {
     s:
      { pkFactory: [Function],
        db: [Db],
        topology: [Server],
        dbName: 'imgSaveTest',
        options: [Object],
        namespace: 'imgSaveTest.uploads.files',
        readPreference: [ReadPreference],
        slaveOk: true,
        serializeFunctions: undefined,
        raw: undefined,
        promoteLongs: undefined,
        promoteValues: undefined,
        promoteBuffers: undefined,
        internalHint: null,
        collectionHint: null,
        name: 'uploads.files',
        promiseLibrary: [Function: Promise],
        readConcern: undefined,
        writeConcern: undefined } } }
```

> gfs.collection('uploads');

You can see that there is no collection function inside it, but it works even it doesn't exist on console.
So the question is where does collection function come from?

Thanks.

Comment: Dragons and magic await you on your journey to learn the awesome language of JavaScript

Comment: What exactly is your question?  When you say "How is it possible?", it is not clear what you are asking about.  Any object that inherits from `EventEmitter` will automatically support methods such as `.on()` and `.emit()`.  Or, an object can even implement methods like that itself.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking about exactly, but you're printing the content of `Grid`, and then calling the `collection` method on a different object (result from calling `Grid` as a function).

Comment: On a serious note just read their code that's the main source of truth and will give you insight on what they did.

Comment: Just read the source here's the collection on the prototype clear as day. https://github.com/aheckmann/gridfs-stream/blob/master/lib/index.js#L75

Comment: Thank you @Darkrum.

Answer (score 0):

In this case

```
let app = express()
```

express functions is called and its functions are visible in console when you logged it.

But in this case

```
const Grid = require('gridfs-stream');
```

Grid is not yet called and you are checking for function after it is called. Try to console gfs after GFS is called

```
gfs = Grid(conn.db, mongoose.mongo);
console.log(gfs)
```

Comment: Thank you for replying but, would like to check my revised text?

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't know even now why collection function isn't on console but, here is the answer I want to.

link: https://github.com/qkreltms/mongodb_simple_file_upload_to_db_example/blob/master/app.js

```
Grid.prototype.collection = function (name) {
  this.curCol = name || this.curCol || this.mongo.GridStore.DEFAULT_ROOT_COLLECTION;
  return this._col = this.db.collection(this.curCol + ".files");
}
```